# Error transformation world to local position

Tags: c++, math, matrix

For a custom engine I'm having trouble with the world to local position of a children transform. I don't have any issue when there is any scale or any position on the parents, but as soon as there is a rotation on the parent (if only a x value seems to works fine) the position rapidly increase (x, y, z).

Here is how I'm turning a local to world transform:

```c
void TransformsManager::SetComponentFromWorldTransform(
    const EntityIndex entityIndex,
    const math::Transform& worldTransform)
{
    //If the entity has no parent, the worldTransform == localTransform
    if (parents_[entityIndex] == kNoParent) {
        SetComponent(entityIndex, worldTransform);
    } else {
        const auto p = worldTransform.GetLocalPosition();
        const auto localPos = (GetWorldToLocalMatrix(parents_[entityIndex]) * math::Vec4(p.x, p.y, p.z, 1)).To3();

        //Works fine
        const auto localScale = GetLocalScaleFromWorldScale(
            entityIndex,
            worldTransform.GetLocalScale());

        //Works fine
        const auto localRotation = GetLocalRotationFromWorldRotation(
            entityIndex,
            worldTransform.GetLocalRotation());

        SetComponent(entityIndex, math::Transform(localPos, localRotation, localScale));
    }
}
```

The function ton get my world to local matrix

```
math::Matrix4 TransformsManager::GetWorldToLocalMatrix(const EntityIndex entityIndex)
{
    if ((dirtyFlags_[entityIndex] & math::TransformDirtyFlagStatus::IS_WORLD_DIRTY) == math::TransformDirtyFlagStatus::IS_WORLD_DIRTY) {
        worldToLocalMatrices_[entityIndex] = math::Matrix4::GetInverse(GetLocalToWorldMatrix(entityIndex));

        dirtyFlags_[entityIndex] &= ~math::TransformDirtyFlagStatus::
            IS_WORLD_DIRTY;
    }
    return worldToLocalMatrices_[entityIndex];
}
```

The function to Get the world matrix

```c
math::Matrix4 TransformsManager::GetLocalToWorldMatrix(const EntityIndex entityIndex)
{
    if ((dirtyFlags_[entityIndex] & math::TransformDirtyFlagStatus::IS_LOCAL_DIRTY) ==
        math::TransformDirtyFlagStatus::IS_LOCAL_DIRTY) {
        if (parents_[entityIndex] == kNoParent) {
            localToWorldMatrices_[entityIndex] = CalculateLocalToParentMatrix(entityIndex);
        } else {
            localToWorldMatrices_[entityIndex] =
                GetLocalToWorldMatrix(parents_[entityIndex]) * CalculateLocalToParentMatrix(entityIndex);
        }
        dirtyFlags_[entityIndex] &= ~math::TransformDirtyFlagStatus::IS_LOCAL_DIRTY;
    }
    return localToWorldMatrices_[entityIndex];
}
```

And the function to compute the final matrix

```c
math::Matrix4 TransformsManager::CalculateLocalToParentMatrix(
    const EntityIndex entityIndex) const
{
    const auto transform = transforms_[entityIndex];

    auto parentMatrix = math::Matrix4::Identity();
    parentMatrix = math::Matrix4::Translate(
        parentMatrix,
        transform.GetLocalPosition());

    const auto localRotation = transform.GetLocalRotation();

    parentMatrix = math::Matrix4::Rotate(
        parentMatrix,
        localRotation.x,
        math::Vec3(1, 0, 0));

    parentMatrix = math::Matrix4::Rotate(
        parentMatrix,
        localRotation.y,
        math::Vec3(0, 1, 0));

    parentMatrix = math::Matrix4::Rotate(
        parentMatrix,
        localRotation.z,
        math::Vec3(0, 0, 1));

    parentMatrix = math::Matrix4::Scale(
        parentMatrix,
        transform.GetLocalScale());

    return parentMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed, I had an error with GetInverse()